# C# Control/Component/Editor for math function controlling

Tags: c#, winforms, editor, mapping, curve

I need a control/component for .NET WinForms where I can edit a function curve that maps input (X) to output (Y). Here is an example screen shot taken from FL Studio:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAdOo.png

Photoshop also uses curve editors for many things, like as many other applications.
Where I can find something suitable, but for .NET especially for Winforms? Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: did you already googled? SO is not the best place to look for it. As an alternative, search on codeproject.com